# Python data structure for auto-requeueing queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, deque

Are there any standard library data structures for a queue that automatically requeues to the opposite end of the queue when an item is popped off the end? This feels like a common problem so I imagine that there could be a simple data structure that does this.

For example:

```
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

queue = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

while True:
    item = queue.pop()
    queue.appendleft(item)
    print(item)
    sleep(5)
```

Is the above code actually optimal, or is there a better way to solve this problem?
Would it be better to just use a list and modify an index value each iteration of the loop to change which place in the list is accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### deque.rotate()

`collections.deque' can be indexed like a list and has a rotate method.

```
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

queue = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

while True:
    item = queue[0]
    queue.rotate(1)
    print(item)
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called a rotation. Deque has this as a builtin: [`deque.rotate(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate).

> Rotate the deque n steps to the right. If n is negative, rotate to the left.
>
> When the deque is not empty, rotating one step to the right is equivalent to `d.appendleft(d.pop())`, and rotating one step to the left is equivalent to `d.append(d.popleft())`.

Usage:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> dq = deque()
>>> dq.append(4)
>>> dq.append(5)
>>> dq.append(6)
>>> dq
deque([4, 5, 6])
>>> dq.rotate()
>>> dq
deque([6, 4, 5])
>>> dq.rotate(2)
>>> dq
deque([4, 5, 6])
>>> dq.rotate(-2)
>>> dq
deque([6, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

This should probably do what you need, and be very efficient.